# Possible statistical modeling method for identifying dynamic influence of different factors over time

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, dynamic-regression

I'm trying to build a statistical model which could capture the dynamic influence of different factors over years, for example, customers who buy a specific brand over different years, and I'm trying to see how the impact of their income level and education level could change over years. We don't have specifically the same customers for different years. I'm looking at dynamic factor analysis and a potential time-series-based dynamic regression model right now, but the thing is that their dependent variable points to a specific value, but under my assumption here the sample data is just those who are the targeted customers (dependent variable could just be one) and my focus is to capture the dynamic coefficients over different factors, so is there any suggestion on some of the best methods to approach this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "factor"? Is it a measured attribute or a latent construct?

Comment: They are meant to be measured attributes such as their income level which could be collected.

Comment: then I'm removing tag "factor analysis"